# How do I charge to create a business card template for multiple people to use

Tags: business

I created a business card design for a company and they need the cards for the Owner and GM. Should I charge for two designs or one if I'm changing name, contact info, etc.?

Comment: Is it two designs or just one?

Answer (score 1):

You charge a base price for the overall design of the business card.

Then you could charge some aditional fee for the adaptation of each combination of name and personal info.

Send them a worksheet with very clear colums so they write the exact data they nead on each one, with the correct usage of Caps for example. Some names are tricky to write, like McCloud.

One or two changes are easy, but if the company has 300 empoyees, probably you need to prepare a batch process or "data merge system" for example https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/data-merge.html.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it is **one** card design and merely two different contacts (both using the same overall design)....

I customarily charge $X to design the card. Then I provide the first 5 names free. Every name after 5 costs $x amount.

Using random amounts, to give a better idea.....

I charge $100 to design the overall business card.
Client needs 30 different names (each using the same design)
I'd set up the first 5 names free. 
Name 6 through 30 would then cost additional $5 per name.
This equates to -- ($100 design) + ($5/name * 25) = $225.00 total fee to client for 30 cards.